# Why am I getting memory leaks iOS5 ARC project on UICalloutView?

Tags: memory-leaks, ios5, mkannotation, mapkit, callouts

I'm getting memory leaks on an ARC iOS5 project which appear to be from my map annotation callouts.  When I track the leaks they appear to be internal to QuartzCore, MapKit, UIKit -- none of them track back into my code.  Is this a known bug in iOS5 SDK or is there something I can do to fix it?

[image: Snapshot from my leak profile]

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I am getting exactly the same leaks at the moment, as per your screen shot.

Comment: No I never did.  If you find out anything let me know.

Comment: I am also getting this leak in non ARC project. Did you get any luck to resolve this leak.